# Setting and getting cookies in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I'm trying to set and get cookies in a project I'm working on in asp.net mvc4.

This is how I'm setting the cookies:

```
                    var Username = new HttpCookie("Username");
                    Username.Value = model.UserName;
                    Username.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                    Username.Secure = true;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(Username);
```

Then, in other controller action, I'm trying this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Username"];
```

but I'm getting null for that specific cookie. Also, I don't know if that would make a difference but I'm not requesting the cookie in the action in which this current action redirects but in other action. That shouldn't make difference since I'm setting the expiration date +7 days from the creation date.

Answer (score 3):

Laziale,

Your code is perfectly Ok.

This is only due to fact that your cookie is secure.

```
 Username.Secure = true;
```

It does not sent back due to that reason only.
Try remove that line.
It shown perfectly in Request.Cookie collection

Hope helps.